# Dragging text around doesn't work in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, fabricjs

I have a simple fabric JS setup. It works fine. It can render shapes and text. However, it stops working when I try to move the elements around. I can move basic shapes like a rectangle, or a triangle, but when I try to move text, it brakes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) throw new Error("no canvas ref")

    const canvasCur = canvasRef.current
    
    canvasCur.style.width = width + "px"
    canvasCur.style.height = height + "px"

    canvasCur.width = width
    canvasCur.height = height

    const options = {};
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasCur, options);

    // create a rectangle object
    let rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      hasRotatingPoint: false,
    });

    // "add" rectangle onto canvas
    canvas.add(rect);

    console.log(canvas.getObjects()); // get all objects on canvas (rect will be first and only)

    const path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z');
    path.set({ left: 120, top: 120 });
    canvas.add(path);
    const text = new fabric.Text('hello world', { left: 100, top: 100 });
    canvas.add(text);
  }, [width, height])
```

I'm using Next JS and Tailwind.

[image: A picture of Fabric.JS not working]